# Find a first integral ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble finding a first integral for the following system:
$$x'=x\left (1-x^2-\frac{y^2}{2}\right)$$
$$y'=y\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}-y^2\right)$$
Could someone please help me?

Comment: This seems to be a gradient system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a planar gradient system. Let $f(x,y)=x(1-x^2-y^2/2)$ and $g(x,y)=y(1-x^2/2 -y^2)$. Notice that $\partial_yf=\partial_xg$.

The idea is to find a real valued function $V(x,y)$ such that $\partial_xV=f$ and $\partial_yV=g$. finding antiderivatives for $f$ and $g$ gives

\begin{aligned}
V(x,y)=\int f(x,y)\,dx &= \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^2y^2}{4} + \phi(y)\\
V(x,y)=\int g(x,y)\,dy &= \frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{x^2y^2}{4} -\frac{y^3}{3} + \psi(x)
\end{aligned}

Equating this expression gives $\phi(y)=\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{y^3}{3}$ and $\psi(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}$. All in all,

$$
V(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{y^3}{3} -\frac{x^2y^2}{4}
$$